# SSIS package with parameters is ignoring the parameter

Tags: ssis

I have an ssis package with 3 connections.  1 ODBC and 2 ADO.  They all have parameters for username and password but when I execute the package, the ODBC parameters don't work!  I have the variables set up and pointing at the package expressions correctly.  When I execute the package in VS, the package sends up a box that asks for the username and password for the ODBC connection.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the popup for credentials in VS expected or unexpected behaviour? Can you show how you have parameters set up to work (I can think of a variety of options on how to make this happen so I would like to see how you have implemented it)

Comment: Unexpected.  Not sure what is causing it!

Comment: Unexpected.  Not sure what is causing it!  I have 2 parameters for the ODBC connection, UserName and Password.  The parameters are set to Required.

Comment: Can you take screenshots of how you have have your parameters wired up to the ODBC connection manager and the text of the ConnectionString into your problem so we can see how the connection is made (inline, machine dsn, user dsn, etc)

Comment: I'm running this in vs but I needs to be eventually added to a Sql Agent job.  The dsn names are the same.